# Xamarin.Android: Is it possible to link a non-list element in data to UI?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-adapter, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to link data to UI in my sample **App**. Coming from a WPF background, my first choice was `DataBinding`, but then I found out that it is not natively supported in **Android** or in `Xamarin.Android`. Of course, I could use some extensions to do just that, but I'd rather use something natively supported, like `Adapters`. In case of e.g., `ListView` elements, I could find many tutorials on how to populate them with data using `Adapters`, but I don't know if I can link a single element (e.g., only a variable) to data this way.

To illustrate what I have in mind: a very rudimentary sample project would be something like prompt the user for a number than display Hello World *number* times using a ´for´ loop. Is it possible to accomplish this using adapters, or I should look for a better alternative? I would rather learn the use of something natively suported first, as I have little xp with `Xamarin.Android`. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To illustrate what I have in mind: a very rudimentary sample project would be something like prompt the user for a number than display Hello World number times using a ´for´ loop. Is it possible to accomplish this using adapters, or I should look for a better alternative?

Yes, it is possible to accomplish this using adapter. But not with the default adapter, but with a custom adapter like below:

```
public class MyListAdapter : Java.Lang.Object,IListAdapter
{
    public int Count {
        get {
            //list view will show 10 lines of data
            return 10;
        }
    }

    public bool HasStableIds { get { return false; } }

    public bool IsEmpty { get { return false; } }

    public int ViewTypeCount { get { return 1; } }

    private Context context;

    private string uniqueData;
    //default constructor
    public MyListAdapter()
    { }

    //constructor with current context and the data you want to show in your listview
    public MyListAdapter(Context c,string data)
    {
        context = c;
        uniqueData = data;
    }

    public bool AreAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public int GetItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        View et=convertView;
        if (et == null)
        {
            et = new TextView(context);
            (et as TextView).Text = uniqueData;
        }
        return et; 

    }

    public bool IsEnabled(int position)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void RegisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer)
    {

    }

    public void UnregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer)
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see, `Count.get` return the loop number of your listview, and in `GetView` I created a `TextView` programmatically, which takes the string data passed by the constructor.

And thus I can use it like below:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    ListView myListView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        myListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.MyListView);
        myListView.Adapter=new MyListAdapter(this,"this is my custom data");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks neat! It is equally possible to use something similar to this if I have several UI elements, right?  In this case, the data side would be a collection (an array or a list etc.), and the UI would have some TextViews or Buttons.

Comment: If you have several UI elements, you will need to change the overrided `GetView` method. You can refer to [this document](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown). It didn't use the `IListAdapter`. But the idea is the same.